# Why does setting runtimepath do nothing?

Tags: vimrc, gvim, microsoft-windows

I'm trying to adjust my `vimrc` to be portable and also run under Gvim 8 on Windows 10. I use Vundle as my package manager and it works perfectly on my Ubuntu machine. However, on Windows, it won't load. I've traced the problem to this line:

```
set rtp+="$HOME\\vimfiles\\bundle\\Vundle.vim\\"
```

After exploring the situation, I discovered that *any* path I give to `runtimepath` turns into the empty string. I've tried every combination of path separator characters, I've tried absolute paths, relative paths, paths using environment variables, everything. I've tried to set it to various paths on my machine which are simple enough that there's no possibility of typos. Regardless of what I set, `rtp` doesn't get changed.

After failing with the above, I started setting `rtp` using `=` instead of `+=`. When doing this, no matter what I set, `echo &rtp` is empty.

What do I need to do to convince vim to **really** set the runtime path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case the double quote `"` starts a comment.

After removing the comment you have:

```
set rtp+=
```

While double (or single) quotes are normally used to enclose strings, the syntax for setting options is different.
The `set` command predates Vim and was available in the original Vi.

PS: You can use forward slashes for runtimepath.

Comment: Worth adding that the normally you need double or single quotes for strings, but options have a different syntax.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You are right, updated.